# Procedure for inserting duplicate record is not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want that user should be able to insert the same `STORE_CODE` again. He can update the same store code as many times he wants. But inserting the new store code can be done once. So for that I created a `Stored procedure` but still I am able to insert the same `store_code` twice, or sometime thrice.

```
  PROCEDURE INSERT_INTO_RRSOC_MST
  (    
    P_STORE_CODE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STATE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_CITY IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SITE_STORE_FORMAT IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STORE_SITENAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1 IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2 IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STORE_MANAGER_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_MANAGER_MOBNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_EMP_NEAREST_STORE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SUPERVISOR_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SUPERVISOR_MOBNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NAME_ALIGNED_LPO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_LPO_MOBILENO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ALPM_ALPO_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_AREA_MANAGER_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ZONAL_HEAD_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_DVR_IP_ADDRESS IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NEAREST_HOSP_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO IN NVARCHAR2,    
    P_STORE_ADDRESS IN NVARCHAR2,    
    P_STORE_SPACE_SQFT IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_LAUNCH_DATE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_CST_TIN_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STORE_EMAILID IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NO_OF_POS IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NO_OF_CAMERA IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY IN NVARCHAR2,    
    P_CAMERA_MODEL IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_FACILTY_TEAMNAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_FACILITY_TEAMNO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_LPA IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SLP_STATE_HEAD IN NVARCHAR2,    
    P_SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_CREATED_BY IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_CREATED_DATE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_LAST_UPDATED_BY IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_LAST_UPDATED_DATE IN NVARCHAR2,    
    P_ISACTIVE IN CHAR,
    P_LATITUDE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_LONGITUDE IN NVARCHAR2, 
    P_SLP_STATE_EMAILID IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ZONAL_ECNUMBER IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ZONAL_EMAILID IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_IS_STORE_IN_MALL IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_IS_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_AVAIL IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_IS_NIGHT_PATROL_PARTY_AVAIL IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_PATROL_PARTY_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_PATROL_PARTY_NO IN NVARCHAR2,
    
    P_ALPM_ALPO_EMAILID IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_ALIGNED_LPO_ECNUMBER IN NVARCHAR2,
    
    P_Indication IN NUMBER,
    TBLDATA OUT NVARCHAR2
  ) 
  
  AS
  
  V_RRSOC_ID NUMBER:=0;
  
  BEGIN
    
    SELECT COUNT(RRSOC_ID) INTO V_RRSOC_ID FROM TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO WHERE STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;
    
    IF V_RRSOC_ID > 0 AND  P_Indication = 1 THEN
    
                              UPDATE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO 
                              SET                                
                                  STATE = P_STATE,
                                  CITY = P_CITY,
                                  SITE_STORE_FORMAT = P_SITE_STORE_FORMAT,
                                  STORE_SITENAME = P_STORE_SITENAME,
                                  STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1 = P_STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1,
                                  STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2 = P_STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2,
                                  STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME = P_STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME,
                                  STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO = P_STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO,
                                  STORE_MANAGER_NAME = P_STORE_MANAGER_NAME,
                                  MANAGER_MOBNO = P_MANAGER_MOBNO,
                                  EMP_NEAREST_STORE = P_EMP_NEAREST_STORE,
                                  EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO = P_EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO,
                                  SUPERVISOR_NAME = P_SUPERVISOR_NAME,
                                  SUPERVISOR_MOBNO = P_SUPERVISOR_MOBNO,
                                  SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE = P_SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE,
                                  SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE = P_SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE,
                                  NAME_ALIGNED_LPO = P_NAME_ALIGNED_LPO,
                                  LPO_MOBILENO = P_LPO_MOBILENO,
                                  ALPM_ALPO_NAME = P_NAME_ALIGNED_LPO,
                                  ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO = P_LPO_MOBILENO,
                                  AREA_MANAGER_NAME = P_AREA_MANAGER_NAME,
                                  AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO = P_AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO,
                                  SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME = P_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME,
                                  SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NO = P_ZONAL_HEAD_NO,
                                  DVR_IP_ADDRESS = P_DVR_IP_ADDRESS,
                                  SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS = P_SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS,
                                  NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME = P_NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME,
                                  NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO = P_NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO,
                                  NEAREST_HOSP_NAME = P_NEAREST_HOSP_NAME,
                                  NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO = P_NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO,
                                  NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME = P_NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME,
                                  NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO = P_NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO,
                                  STORE_SPACE_SQFT = P_STORE_SPACE_SQFT,
                                  LAUNCH_DATE = TO_DATE(P_LAUNCH_DATE, 'DD-MM-RR'),
                                  CST_TIN_NO = P_CST_TIN_NO,
                                  STORE_EMAILID = P_STORE_EMAILID,
                                  NO_OF_POS = P_NO_OF_POS,
                                  NO_OF_CAMERA = P_NO_OF_CAMERA,
                                  DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY = P_DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY,
                                  CAMERA_MODEL = P_CAMERA_MODEL,
                                  ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID = P_ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID,
                                  FACILTY_TEAMNAME = P_FACILTY_TEAMNAME,
                                  FACILITY_TEAMNO = P_FACILITY_TEAMNO,
                                  STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME = P_STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME,
                                  STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO = P_STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO,
                                  LPA = P_LPA,
                                  SLP_STATE_HEAD = P_SLP_STATE_HEAD,
                                  SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO = P_SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO,
                                --  CREATED_BY = 
                                --  CREATED_DATE = 
                                  LAST_UPDATED_BY = P_LAST_UPDATED_BY,
                                  LAST_UPDATED_DATE = SYSDATE,
                                  ISACTIVE = P_ISACTIVE,
                                  LATITUDE = P_LATITUDE,
                                  LONGITUDE = P_LONGITUDE,
                                  SLP_STATE_EMAILID = P_SLP_STATE_EMAILID,
                                  STORE_ADDRESS = P_STORE_ADDRESS,                                  
                                  SLP_ZONAL_ECNUMBER = P_ZONAL_ECNUMBER,
                                  SLP_ZONAL_EMAILID = P_ZONAL_EMAILID,
                                  SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER = P_SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER,
                                  ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER = P_ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER,                                  
                                  
                                  MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO = P_MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO,
                                  NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME = P_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME,
                                  NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO = P_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO,
                                  PATROL_PARTY_NAME = P_PATROL_PARTY_NAME,
                                  PATROL_PARTY_NO =  P_PATROL_PARTY_NO,
                                  
                                  ALPM_ALPO_EMAILID = P_ALPM_ALPO_EMAILID,
                                  ALIGNED_LPO_ECNUMBER = P_ALIGNED_LPO_ECNUMBER
                                  
                                                        
                              WHERE STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;
                           -- RETURNING RRSOC_ID INTO TBLDATA;  
          --SELECT RRSOC_ID INTO TBLDATA FROM TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO WHERE STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;   
          
          TBLDATA:='Record updated successfully';
    
    ELSE
    
     SELECT COUNT(RRSOC_ID) INTO V_RRSOC_ID FROM TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO WHERE STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;
    
     IF V_RRSOC_ID = 0 AND  P_Indication = 0 THEN
    
    INSERT INTO TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO      
                                   (
                                          STORE_CODE,
                                          STATE,     
                                          CITY,      
                                          SITE_STORE_FORMAT,
                                          STORE_SITENAME,   
                                          STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1,
                                          STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2,
                                          STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME,
                                          STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO,
                                          STORE_MANAGER_NAME,      
                                          MANAGER_MOBNO,           
                                          EMP_NEAREST_STORE,
                                          EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO, 
                                          SUPERVISOR_NAME,         
                                          SUPERVISOR_MOBNO,        
                                          SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE, 
                                          SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE,
                                          NAME_ALIGNED_LPO,        
                                          LPO_MOBILENO,            
                                          ALPM_ALPO_NAME,          
                                          ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO,         
                                          AREA_MANAGER_NAME,       
                                          AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO,      
                                          SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME,         
                                          SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NO,           
                                          DVR_IP_ADDRESS,          
                                          SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS,       
                                          NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME, 
                                          NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO,
                                          NEAREST_HOSP_NAME,        
                                          NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO,      
                                          NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME,
                                          NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO,  
                                          STORE_ADDRESS,            
                                          STORE_SPACE_SQFT,
                                          LAUNCH_DATE,              
                                          CST_TIN_NO,               
                                          STORE_EMAILID,            
                                          NO_OF_POS,                
                                          NO_OF_CAMERA,             
                                          DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY,     
                                          CAMERA_MODEL,             
                                          ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID,      
                                          FACILTY_TEAMNAME,         
                                          FACILITY_TEAMNO,          
                                          STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME,      
                                          STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO,        
                                          LPA,                      
                                          SLP_STATE_HEAD,           
                                          SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO,        
                                          CREATED_BY,               
                                          CREATED_DATE,             
                                          LAST_UPDATED_BY,          
                                          LAST_UPDATED_DATE,        
                                          ISACTIVE,                 
                                          LATITUDE,                 
                                          LONGITUDE,
                                          SLP_STATE_EMAILID,
                                          
                                          
                                          SLP_ZONAL_ECNUMBER,
                                          SLP_ZONAL_EMAILID,
                                          SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER,
                                          ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER,
                                          IS_STORE_IN_MALL,
                                          MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO,
                                          IS_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_AVAIL,
                                          NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME,
                                          NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO,
                                          IS_NIGHT_PATROL_PARTY_AVAIL,
                                          PATROL_PARTY_NAME,
                                          PATROL_PARTY_NO,
                                          ALPM_ALPO_EMAILID,
                                          ALIGNED_LPO_ECNUMBER
                                          
                                   )
            
     VALUES
                                   (            
                                          P_STORE_CODE,
                                          P_STATE,
                                          P_CITY,
                                          P_SITE_STORE_FORMAT,
                                          P_STORE_SITENAME,
                                          P_STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1,
                                          P_STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2,
                                          P_STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME,
                                          P_STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO,
                                          P_STORE_MANAGER_NAME,
                                          P_MANAGER_MOBNO,
                                          P_EMP_NEAREST_STORE,
                                          P_EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO,
                                         P_SUPERVISOR_NAME,
                                          P_SUPERVISOR_MOBNO,
                                          P_SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE,
                                          P_SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE,
                                          P_NAME_ALIGNED_LPO,
                                          P_LPO_MOBILENO,
                                          P_ALPM_ALPO_NAME,
                                          P_ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO,
                                          P_AREA_MANAGER_NAME,
                                          P_AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO,
                                          P_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME,
                                          P_ZONAL_HEAD_NO,
                                          P_DVR_IP_ADDRESS,
                                          P_SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS,
                                          P_NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME,
                                          P_NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO,
                                          P_NEAREST_HOSP_NAME,
                                          P_NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO,
                                          P_NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME,
                                          P_NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO,    
                                          P_STORE_ADDRESS,    
                                          P_STORE_SPACE_SQFT,
                                          TO_DATE (P_LAUNCH_DATE, 'dd-mm-yy'),
                                          P_CST_TIN_NO,
                                          P_STORE_EMAILID,
                                          P_NO_OF_POS,
                                          P_NO_OF_CAMERA,
                                          P_DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY,    
                                          P_CAMERA_MODEL,
                                          P_ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID,
                                          P_FACILTY_TEAMNAME,
                                          P_FACILITY_TEAMNO,
                                          P_STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME,
                                          P_STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO,
                                          P_LPA,
                                          P_SLP_STATE_HEAD,    
                                          P_SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO,
                                          P_CREATED_BY,
                                          SYSDATE,
                                          P_LAST_UPDATED_BY,
                                          SYSDATE,    
                                          P_ISACTIVE,
                                          P_LATITUDE,
                                          P_LONGITUDE,
                                          P_SLP_STATE_EMAILID,
                                          
                                          P_ZONAL_ECNUMBER,
                                          P_ZONAL_EMAILID,
                                          P_SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER,
                                          P_ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER,
                                          P_IS_STORE_IN_MALL,
                                          P_MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO,
                                          P_IS_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_AVAIL,
                                          P_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME,
                                          P_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO,
                                          P_IS_NIGHT_PATROL_PARTY_AVAIL,
                                          P_PATROL_PARTY_NAME,
                                          P_PATROL_PARTY_NO,
                                          P_ALPM_ALPO_EMAILID,
                                          P_ALIGNED_LPO_ECNUMBER
                                   ) 
                                   
                                   RETURNING RRSOC_ID INTO TBLDATA;
          TBLDATA:='Record Saved Succesfully';  
          
          ELSE
          
           TBLDATA:='Record already exist';  
          
          END IF;
  END IF;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISE;
        ROLLBACK;
  
  END INSERT_INTO_RRSOC_MST;
```

Comment: Can't you simplify that? Not in real life, but while asking a question? Why can't you store that code more than once? Any error? Which one?

Comment: @Littlefoot: No error. It simply accepting the same store code twice.!!

Comment: *"It simply accepting the same store code twice.!!"* (1) put a unique constraint on STORE_CODE. (2) Use a MERGE statement instead of INSERT + UPDATE.

Comment: Also, as a matter of courtesy to the strangers who you are asking for help, you really should take the effort to craft a small reproducible example instead of expecting us to scroll through hundreds of lines of code trying to understand what it does.

Comment: Isn't this something that a unique constraint on the table could help prevent?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of

- check if the record exists
- if it does, then update
- if it does not, then insert

is flawed for any genuine application that has more than a single user. Because all you need is two people running the code at the same time and each will not see the others uncommitted changes and voila...broken database.

The *only* way to ensure that you do not get duplicates is to define a unique constraint on the columns that define uniqueness for this table. Based on your code, this would appear to be STORE_CODE.

With such a unique constraint in place, you will not get a duplicate because any attempt to do so will block on of the people trying to do it.

If you are in the (odd) position of that you want to allow more than 1 store code, but need to do something special on the first occurrence of it, then you'll need a more sophisticated locking strategy to handle that (because it also suggests perhaps a problem with the database design).

There are examples how to do this on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=concurrent-users-preventing-duplicated-records)